# Turning text with hours and minutes to minutes

Tags: r, time, extract

I have got a big dataframe that look like this:

| from | to | distance in km | traveltime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1033 | 1076 | 1.8 | 6 mins |
| 1035 | 1076 | 2.6 | 1 min |
| 1036 | 1076 | 2.4 | 1 hour 26 mins |
| 1037 | 1076 | 6.7 | 3 hours 1 min |

i want get the traveltime column to show the traveltime in minutes, so like this:

| from | to | distance in km | traveltime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1033 | 1076 | 1.8 | 6 |
| 1035 | 1076 | 2.6 | 1 |
| 1036 | 1076 | 2.4 | 86 |
| 1037 | 1076 | 6.7 | 181 |

I have tried the `hm()` function but it doesn't work on the values which are smaller than 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this wrapping a time transformation in nested replacements for strings:

```
#Code
df$NewTime <- unname(sapply(sub('s','',sub("\\s+min",
                  "", sub("hour|hours", "* 60 +", df$traveltime))), 
              function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
```

Output:

```
df
  from   to distance.in.km     traveltime NewTime
1 1033 1076            1.8         6 mins       6
2 1035 1076            2.6          1 min       1
3 1036 1076            2.4 1 hour 26 mins      86
4 1037 1076            6.7  3 hours 1 min     181
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(from = c(1033L, 1035L, 1036L, 1037L), to = c(1076L, 
1076L, 1076L, 1076L), distance.in.km = c(1.8, 2.6, 2.4, 6.7), 
    traveltime = c("6 mins", "1 min", "1 hour 26 mins", "3 hours 1 min"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Another option using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
#Code 2
df$NewTime <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$traveltime, "\\d+"), function(x) {
  x1 <- as.numeric(x)
  if(length(x1)>1) x1[1]*60 + x1[2] else x1 })
```

It will produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be by extracting the number substrings. First, get the numbers into a list and then convert hours into minutes by multiplying 60.

```
matches <- regmatches(df$traveltime, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", df$traveltime))
hr_mins <- lapply(matches, function(x){
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  if(length(x) > 1) x[1] * 60 + x[2] else x
})
df$traveltime <-  unlist(hr_mins)
```

---

**Output**

```
  from   to distance.in.km traveltime
1 1033 1076            1.8          6
2 1035 1076            2.6          1
3 1036 1076            2.4         86
4 1037 1076            6.7        181
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(from = c(1033, 1035, 1036, 1037), to = c(1076, 
1076, 1076, 1076), distance.in.km = c(1.8, 2.6, 2.4, 6.7), traveltime = c("6 mins", 
"1 min", "1 hour 26 mins", "3 hours 1 min")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `traveltime` to `lubridate`'s `period` object, convert the period object to number of seconds and divide it by 60 to get duration in minutes.

```
library(lubridate)
df$travel_min <- period_to_seconds(period(df$traveltime))/60
df

#  from   to distance.in.km     traveltime travel_min
#1 1033 1076            1.8         6 mins          6
#2 1035 1076            2.6          1 min          1
#3 1036 1076            2.4 1 hour 26 mins         86
#4 1037 1076            6.7  3 hours 1 min        181
```